# Leitura de char e string em c++

Tags: c++, string, char, scanf

Eu tenho que colocar um numero inteiro, um real, um caractere e uma frase contendo espaços ate 100 caracteres. tentei fazer a solução mas, so consigo digitar os números e não esta saindo o caractere e a string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int numero;
float real;
char carac;
string frase;

int main(){

    cin>>numero;
    cin>>real;
    cin>>carac;
    getline(cin,frase);



    cout<<numero;
    cout<<fixed;
    cout.precision(6);
    cout<<real<<carac<<frase<<endl;
```

Comment: E por que está misturando C com C++? Por que não faz tudo em C++?

Comment: porque so com um tambem não dá pra ler separado. tive que fazer assim

Comment: Claro que dá, e é o certo, criar novas complicações não resolve o problema. Tente resolver do jeito certo que é mais fácil.

Comment: beleza coloquei todos com cin, mas ainda quando termino de gitar o acarctere a finaliza o progrma e nem le a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `getline` apanha a quebra de linha que ficou na ultima leitura feita com:

```
cin>>carac;
```

E por isso nem lhe permite digitar nada.

Uma solução simples é consumir a quebra de linha que ficou utilizando [`cin.ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/):

```
cin >> numero;
cin >> real;
cin >> carac;
cin.ignore(); // <-- consumir aqui antes do getline
getline(cin,frase);
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/0gfG11) <sub>(ajustei os `couts` para ser mais facil de ler)</sub>

Lembre-se que tanto pode encadear as leituras no `cin` como no `cout` simplificando o código. O mesmo se aplica para o `fixed` e `precision` ou `setprecision`. Por isso o seu código pode ficar apenas:

```
cin >> numero >> real >> carac;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,frase);

cout << numero << fixed << setprecision(6) << real << carac << frase << endl;
```